# jax-ws with intermediate https proxy and https endpoint does not work

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, jax-ws, websphere-7

Problem Description

```
- We are having problems with a JAX-WS Webservice that wants to connect to
a server using HTTPS in combination with a proxy server.

The setups is as follows:
- WebSphere 6.0.1.47 running on AIX Version: 5300-10-07-1119

- A JAX-WS Webservice application


What happens is as follows:
JAX-WS application in WAS tries to connect to
'https://target.example.domain/url'  while using a proxy server
- When the transport chain is started, the following error appears (i have
included the corresponding ffdc's as attachments to this mail) :
java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 76  A socket
must be already connected.;


When we:
1) Use a HTTP destination and DO NOT use a Proxy Server then the
application works
2) Use a HTTPS destination and DO NOT use a Proxy Server then the
application works
3) Use a HTTP destination and USE a Proxy Server then the 
application works
4) Use a HTTPS destination and USE a Proxy Server then the application
displays the error described above.

ffdc logs
```

"  ------Start of DE processing------ = [1/14/15 13:04:39:913 CET] , key =                    java.io.IOException com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection.connect 213
    Exception = java.io.IOException
    Source = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection.connect
    probeid = 213
    Stack Dump = java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 76      A socket must be already connected.
        at     com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:679)
        at     com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$CompletionProcessingRunnable.run(ResultHandler.ja    va:910)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)

```
Dump of callerThis = 
Object type = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection@db30db3

Exception = java.io.IOException
Source = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection.connect
probeid = 213
Dump of callerThis = 
Object type = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection
  _tc = 
    defaultMessageFile = com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
    EXTENSION_NAME_DPID = DiagnosticProvider
    ivDumpEnabled = false
    ivResourceBundleName = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.resources.websvcsMessages
    ivLogger = null
    ivDiagnosticProviderID = null
    anyTracingEnabled = true
    ivLevel = 1
    ivName = com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPConnection
    ivDebugEnabled = true
    ivEventEnabled = true
    ivEntryEnabled = true
    ivDetailEnabled = true
    ivConfigEnabled = true
    ivInfoEnabled = true
    ivServiceEnabled = true
    ivWarningEnabled = true
    ivErrorEnabled = true
    ivFatalEnabled = true
      chainname = HttpsOutboundChain:xx-proxy-                      xxxxx.xxx.xxxx.com:8080:1665256594:10.21.197.161:9443
 ............."
```

We have tried setting the properties (https.proxyHost, https.proxyPort) at       System level and also in the SOAP header, nothing works.
We are using BindingProv

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you try turning off keep alive?